# React Material UI: floating label on something else than input

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I made a custom component that doesn't rely on Input (it is actually showing a path selection within a tree)

I want to integrate this component in my application with the very same look and feel than any other input component. What I actually want is the floating label that takes place within the editor if the value is null or undefined, and floats above the editor if the editor has a value.

I can't find any way that permits to achieve this on components that are not based on an Input. Am I missing something in material ui documentation?

Here is the code sandbox of my development: https://codesandbox.io/s/treeviewselect-dj4j5?file=/demo.tsx

**Edit**: the boolean property `shrink` that should help to do the trick, but still, the position of the label is still off.

**Edit2**: it seems that the related control must have a height of 64px for the position of the label to be fine. Needs to pilot the whole behavior depending on the value. Will post the fully corrected codesandbox later.